# How do I multiply column values?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I simply want to multiply column `h` with column `j`, and store the result in column `k` in each row.

What do I type in as the formula to do this?

Comment: Thank you so much, I was still in need of this information :)

Answer (score 7):

Add the following formula in `K1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(H:H * J:J)
```

If you have a header in the first row, then do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(H2:H * J2:J)
```

To avoid the remaining zero's, best is to select a fixed range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(H2:H250 * J2:J250)
```

### Reference

[Google Drive Help: ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/71291?hl=en)

Comment: I think OP wants results for each row rather than the array.

Comment: @Raystafarian - The `ARRAYFORMULA` will actually copy down automatically to cover the range in the formula.

Comment: Awesome. I wanted to multiply the values in A by the values in B and sum the result. This worked like a charm: `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(A:A * B:B))`